# Laravel 5.4 check if user is active or not and respond with message if not

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have a custom login controller,
and I need to check if user is active or not and if not respond with message like please active your account first.

Here is my controller

```
public function login( Request $request ) {
        // validate the form data
        $this->validate( $request, [
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ] );
        // attempt to login the supplier in

        if ( Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->attempt(
            [
                'email'    => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ], $request->remember ) ) {

            return redirect()->intended( route( 'supplier-dashboard' ) );
        }

        $errors = [ $this->username() => trans( 'auth.failed' ) ];

        if ( $request->expectsJson() ) {
            return response()->json( $errors, 422 );
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                         ->withInput( $request->only( 'email', 'remember' ) )
                         ->withErrors( $errors );
    }
```

I can just add `active => 1` to the `if ( Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->attempt(` but this will respond with wrong username or password

but I want it to respond with 'Active your account first'

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    if ( Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->attempt(
        [
            'email'    => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ], $request->remember ) ) {
        if(!Auth::user()->active) {
           Auth::logout();
           $errors = ['active' => 'Please activate your account'];
        } else {
           return redirect()->intended( route( 'supplier-dashboard' ) );
        }
    } else {
        $errors = [ $this->username() => trans( 'auth.failed' ) ];
    }
...
```

Comment: sorry to say didn't work it just logged the user in, and Ignored this line.

Comment: it ignored `if(!Auth::user()->active)` line?

Comment: Yes! and I also try this way `if(!Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->active) {
    Auth::logout();
    $errors = ['active' => 'Please activate your account'];
   }` but the `$error` is not reachable it came back with username or password is incorrect

Comment: Well if it came with that message then your `if ( Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->attempt` is failing, because it fetches `$error` from else

Comment: So what you are saying is that even if the user doesn't exist in the database with that username and password you still wanna return `Your account is not active`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but it seems like you are just trying to customize the validation messages. In laravel 5.4 you can customize the error message that the user sees like [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#customizing-the-error-messages).

`You may customize the error messages used by the form request by overriding the messages method. This method should return an array of attribute / rule pairs and their corresponding error messages:`

You should be able to do something like

```
public function messages()
{
     return [
         'email.required' => 'Active your account first',
         'password.required'  => 'Active your account first',
     ];
}
```

But a better way to do this would be using Laravels [flash messaging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session). Essentially you would set a key and message like this:

`$request->session()->flash('message', 'Active your account first');`

Then to display the message in your view you can simply do this:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <p>{!! session('message') !!}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: No I not trying to change or translate the messages, I am trying to check if the user is active or not and if he is not active give him a message `Your account is not active`